# AntD: Config Provider API for customization does not allow text customization

Tags: themes, antd

I am using AntD Config Provider to provide custom styles to certain AntD components. Been playing with the button component and it seems there is only certain things you can change. I seem unable to change the text color of the button. Has anyone figured out how to do this?

These are the attributes I have tried to change for text color with no success. [image: Attributes]

Updates:
The button is of Primary type and the Token attribute is not part of the individual component so it can not be used.

Here is what the code looks like

```
export const SecondaryConfigProvider = (props:any) => {
    return (
        <ConfigProvider 
        theme={{
            components: {
                Button: {
                    colorText: "orange",
                    colorPrimaryBg: "red",
                    colorPrimaryBorder: "red",
                    colorPrimaryBorderHover: "red",
                    colorPrimaryHover: "lightgray",
                    colorPrimary: "blue",
                    colorPrimaryActive: "lightgray",
                    colorPrimaryTextHover: "lightgray",
                    colorPrimaryText: "lightgray",
                    colorPrimaryTextActive: "lightgray",
                    colorBgContainer: "blue",
                    colorBorderBg: "red",
                    controlOutline: "none"
                  }
            }
        }}
        >
        {props.children}
        </ConfigProvider>
    )
}
```

the button layout is here

```
import {Button, DatePicker} from 'antd'
import { PrimaryConfigProvider } from "./PrimaryConfigProvider"
import { SecondaryConfigProvider } from "./SecondaryConfigProvider"
export const TestingConfig = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <PrimaryConfigProvider>
        <Button type="primary">Primary Button</Button>
        </PrimaryConfigProvider>

        <SecondaryConfigProvider>
        <Button  type="primary">Secondary Button</Button>
        </SecondaryConfigProvider>
        </>
    )
}
```

App.jsx -- contains `<TestingConfig/>`

Index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>     
  <Provider store={store}>     
        <App /> 
  </Provider>
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you will go to definition of some Button's token (right click on token then go to definition, or hover token and press F12, or ctrl+click) - you'll be able to see the whole list of them.

```
Button: {
   //others token: value ...
   colorPrimary: 'red',
},
```

If it doesn't help you can I see how do you use `<Button />` in your code? As I can see your screenshot your tokens are defined for primary button, so you need to pass props to your button component as below:

```
<Button type="primary"> I am a button <Button />
```

Comment: The button is primary and the token attribute can not be used within the Button. I have used basically all the text attributes to try to change the color of the text within the button but have still had no success.

Comment: I don't know what are you doing wrong, maybe you have override antd css. Check out my example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-btn-color-k2jz5q?file=/src/App.tsx). For me everything works fine

Comment: I changed my code to look like yours from the sandbox. I changed the imports from @pankod/refine-antd to just antd. I wrapped the second button in the same config that was shown in sandbox env. Do you see any issues present here? I updated the question above.

Comment: Check my CodeSandbox again, I've updated it with yours SecondaryConfigProvider

Comment: It seems there is a conflict between the two config providers even when I close one button in One config provider and another button with a different config provider. I am guessing the approach I am following is not possible.